# Looking for a way to determine how many points are above a certain (nonlinear) line in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, line, polygon, points

I have a big data frame (df) which contains x/y coordinates and a nonlinear regression line that is somewhere in the middle, see plot below. Many points overlap, that's why I have an extra column  $Freq.

[image: Points (a lot of them are overlapping) and the line.]

I am looking for a way to determine how many points (many on top of eachother) are above this line. See the df structure below.

```
head(df)
    x   y  Freq
    0   0  396
    1   1  222
    1   0  513
    2   0  315
    2   1  279
    2   2   36
...
```

I am aware of the polygon methods here on StackOverflow but I can't seem to get those to work, maybe in part due to the fact that my line is a series of coordinates rather than a formula:

```
head(line)
x    y
0 0.0000
1 0.4220
2 0.8350
3 1.2545
4 1.6615
5 2.0450
```

In the end it would be great if I can have three numbers: one that describes the count of the points above the line, the count of the points below the line, and possibly those that are to the right of this particular line.

Thanks!

Comment: 1. where's the formula for your "nonlinear" regression line, 2. what do you do for values >=22?

Comment: Good point, I added a bit where I would like to have three numbers. The nonlinear line is not a formula, it's a list of x,y coordinates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of unknowns here, nevertheless

```
df=merge(df,line,by="x",suffixes=c("_df","_line"))
sum(df$Freq[df$y_df>df$y_line])

[1] 537
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This seems to work quite well. Would this be easy to scale up to many dfs using the same line?

Comment: @tonix Maybe, depends on how you have them stored in your environment.

Comment: As separate data frames, but we could use regular expressions (i.e. df_1, df_2 and so on?)

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble::tribble(
  ~x, ~y, ~Freq,
  0,   0,  396,
  1,   1,  222,
  1,   0,  513,
  2,   0,  315,
  2,   1,  279,
  2,   2,   36
  )
data
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>       x     y  Freq
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     0     0   396
#> 2     1     1   222
#> 3     1     0   513
#> 4     2     0   315
#> 5     2     1   279
#> 6     2     2    36

line <- tibble::tribble(
  ~x, ~y,
  0, 0.0000,
  1, 0.4220,
  2, 0.8350,
  3, 1.2545,
  4, 1.6615,
  5, 2.0450
  )
line
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>       x     y
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     0 0    
#> 2     1 0.422
#> 3     2 0.835
#> 4     3 1.25 
#> 5     4 1.66 
#> 6     5 2.04

data %>%
  left_join(line %>% rename(line_y = y)) %>%
  filter(y > line_y)
#> Joining, by = "x"
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>       x     y  Freq line_y
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1     1     1   222  0.422
#> 2     2     1   279  0.835
#> 3     2     2    36  0.835

data %>%
  left_join(line %>% rename(line_y = y)) %>%
  filter(y > line_y) %>%
  summarise(sum(Freq))
#> Joining, by = "x"
#> # A tibble: 1 x 1
#>   `sum(Freq)`
#>         <dbl>
#> 1         537

data %>%
  left_join(line %>% rename(line_y = y)) %>%
  filter(y > line_y) %>%
  nrow()
#> Joining, by = "x"
#> [1] 3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks!! This is quite similar to the method user2974951 proposed and works quite well! Would this be easy to scale up to many dfs using the same line>?

Comment: yes. you can also do `data <- list(data1, data2, data3) %>% reduce(left_join)`

Comment: Does not seem to work, data gets lost and removes lots of observations

Comment: What are the `colnames` of the other dfs?

Comment: colnames(df1) <- c("x", "y", "Freq") ##55 observations
colnames(df2) <- c("x", "y", "Freq") ##152 observations
colnames(df3) <- c("x", "y", "Freq") ##594 observations
data <- list(df1, df2, df3) %>% reduce(left_join)

data then has 55 observations

Comment: Do you have rows (pairs of x and y) duplicated e.g. present in both df1 and df2?

Comment: Yes, x=0 and y=0 are in all the data frames, as well as the lower numbers (x=1, y=1 / x=0, y =1 etc etc)

Comment: Joining removes duplicated rows. If you want to sum up frequencies occured at the same point (x and y), you can do `list(data1, data2, data3) %>% reduce(bind_rows) %>% group_by(x, y) %>% summarise(Freq = sum(Freq))`.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, much appreciated!